# Unix - Remove internal double quote with terminator comma

Tags: shell, perl, unix, ksh

**Input file:**

```
"1","2col",""3col " "
"2","2col"," "3c,ol     " "
"3","2col"," 3co,l"     
"4","2col","3co,l"
"5","2col",""3co,l      ""              "
"6","2col",""3c,ol ""3c,ol"""
```

**Output file:**

```
"1","2col","3col    "
"2","2col"," 3c,ol       "
"3","2col"," 3co,l"     
"4","2col","3co,l"
"5","2col","3co,l                       "
"6","2col","3c,ol 3c,ol"
```

Please help me to get the above Output using Unix command. Please note the 3rd column is modified in the output, all internal Double Quotes have been removed.

Comma is terminator. When comma is present between Double quote then it is not considered as terminator. See 6th line and after 2nd comma, comma is present as a text between Double quote which is fine.

**What I have tried so far:**

```
sed 's/""|/|/g'
sed -e "s/\"\"//g"
perl -pe 's/(?<!^)(?<!\,)"(?!\,)(?!$)/""/g'
```

Comment: Hi Allan, sed 's/""|/|/g'      and     sed -e "s/\"\"//g"        and      perl -pe 's/(?<!^)(?<!\,)"(?!\,)(?!$)/""/g'

Comment: `perl`'s `Text::CSV` module might well do the trick.

Comment: How come in the 1st line of test example in the input you have 2 trailing spaces: `"1","2col",""3col[ ]"[ ]"` and in the output you have 4 (four) trailing spaces: `"1","2col","3col[ ][ ][ ][ ]"`? Please adjust examples so they accurately match your requirements

Comment: the double quotes are not balanced in record 5... can you clarify that

Comment: @Allan I had already upvoted the below answer few days back.

Comment: @swet: thank you so much! If someone did answer the question could you also accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hypothesis (first and 2nd columns are "clean", they do not contain `,` for example)

**Input:**

```
"1","2col",""3col " "
"2","2col"," "3c,ol     " "
"3","2col"," 3co,l"     
"4","2col","3co,l"
"5","2col",""3co,l      ""              "
"6","2col",""3c,ol ""3c,ol"""
```

**Command:**

```
tr -d '"' < input | awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{$1="\""$1"\"";$2="\""$2"\"";printf $1 OFS $2 OFS "\"";for(u=3;u<=NF;u++){if(u!=NF)printf $u OFS;else printf $u};printf "\"" RS}'
```

**Output:**

```
"1","2col","3col  "
"2","2col"," 3c,ol      "
"3","2col"," 3co,l     "
"4","2col","3co,l"
"5","2col","3co,l                    "
"6","2col","3c,ol 3c,ol"
```

**Explanations:**

- `tr -d '"' < input` will remove all the `"`
- `| awk` pipe the output to `awk`
- `-F',' -v OFS=','` input/output field separator defined as comma
- you surround the first 2 columns with `"` by using `$1="\""$1"\"";$2="\""$2"\"";` and you print them `printf $1 OFS $2 OFS "\"";`
- `for(u=3;u<=NF;u++){if(u!=NF)printf $u OFS;else printf $u};printf "\"" RS}` for the rest of the column you just append them back together and you add the last `"` at the end of the line.

**For readability:**

```
'{
  $1="\""$1"\""
  $2="\""$2"\""
  printf $1 OFS $2 OFS "\""
  for(u=3;u<=NF;u++)
  {
    if(u!=NF)printf $u OFS
    else printf $u
  }
  printf "\"" RS
}'
```

Comment: Will fail for a comma in the first 2 fields: `"1","2,col","3col"`

Comment: @WalterA: I have edited and I have added a disclaimer. In OP post, col1 and 2 look ok, so that's why I have build my solution on this hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Use the quotes for finding the first two fields and concatenate the other fields.

```
awk -F '"' '
   BEGIN {q="\""}
   {printf "%s", q$2q$3q$4q$5q; for (i=6;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s", $i; print q}
   ' inputfile
```

EDIT: An alternative

```
paste -d, <( cut -d"," -f1,2 < inputfile) \
          <( cut -d"," -f3-  < inputfile | sed 's/"//g;s/.*/"&"/')
```

EDIT: Another alternative

`sed 's/old/new/g`: Apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp
`sed`s/old/new/number`: Only replace the numberth match of the regexp.
When you mix the g and number modifiers in GNU sed, the first matces are ignored, and then match and replace all matches.
In this case:

```
sed -r 's/"//g6;s/$/"/' inputfile
```